# HQL: How to check if all vals from regexp_split_to_array are in a list

Tags: arrays, regex, postgresql, split, contains

The following works for single values

if pets is DOG

where pets in ('DOG', 'CAT', 'DRAGON')

---

But, if I have a comma separated list of pets - {DOG, CAT} generated from regexp_split_to_array it does not

This is the idea of what I want to do, but how can it actually be done?

**regexp_split_to_array(pets, ',')  in ('DOG', 'CAT', 'DRAGON')**

Comment: Also, what would be the equivalent for regexp_split_to_array(pets, ',') NOT in ('DOG', 'CAT', 'DRAGON')

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Comment: Java (JBoss/Hibernate), postgres

Comment: I found a way to do it using regex_split_to_table and then doing a join, but that seems sub-optimal

Answer (score 0):

```sql
select regexp_split_to_array(pets, '\s*,\s*') pets
from (
  select 'dog, cat' as pets
  union
  select 'cat, mouse'
  union 
  select 'dragon'
) t
where regexp_split_to_array(pets, '\s*,\s*') && array['dog', 'cat'];
```

```
    pets
-------------
 {dog,cat}
 {cat,mouse}
(2 rows)
```

= = =

```sql
select regexp_split_to_array(pets, '\s*,\s*') pets
from (
  select 'dog, cat' as pets 
  union 
  select 'cat, mouse' 
  union 
  select 'dragon'
) t 
where regexp_split_to_array(pets, '\s*,\s*') && array['dog'];
```

```
   pets
-----------
 {dog,cat}
(1 row)
```